# Bypassing scopes consent screen for non-admin users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, google-apps-marketplace

Google apps marketplace #5 best practice says users shouldn't see the consent screen after an admin installs the app. I have been trying get this working on a Rails app using devise and omniauth-google-oauth2 for authentication. I have setup the app in test domain using an admin account. But non-admin users always see the consent screen. Any idea how to avoid it? https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2 has some help; but setting any of the options specified there didn't help.

My config looks like below:

```
config.omniauth :google_oauth2, "code", "code", { access_type: "online", approval_prompt: "none", include_granted_scopes: "true", prompt: "select_account" }
```

Specifying scopes like "email,profile,calendar,https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/" gives the following error:

```
Error: invalid_scope

Some requested scopes were invalid. {valid=[https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar, https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/], invalid=[https://www.googleapis.com/auth/profile, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/email], noncanonical=[https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/(https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts)]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding

> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me

to the list of scopes in "Google Apps Marketplace SDK" solved the issue. When the domain admin installs the app rest of the domain users will not see the consent screen.

Even my omniauth config is simplified now. It looks like below:

```
config.omniauth :google_oauth2, "XXX.apps.googleusercontent.com", "YYY", { access_type: "online", approval_prompt: "none", include_granted_scopes: "true" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding invalid_scope error, I think you need to use following scopes for profile and email

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile

fyi use https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/ to find out valid scopes for other Google APIs

Comment: This solves the invalid_scope problem. Thanks. But the main problem of consent screen showing up for all users is still there.

Comment: Do you have all these scopes added to Google Apps Marketplace SDK page in Developer console? https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/preparing

Comment: yes I have all the scopes added and they are exactly same as what is being sent as part of oAuth2 request.